# How to select other columns other than group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7

I am actually having a database just like this

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| org_entry_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| check_in     | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| check_out    | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_at   | datetime         | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| updated_at   | datetime         | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| deleted_at   | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Now I want to get id field and max(check_in) from this table and that too groupBy org_entry_id

I have tried query like this but it will give `full groupBy mode` error

```
select id, max(check_in) from time_sheets group by org_entry_id;
```

So I have read the manual and I found that it was written to `ANY_VALUE` but that solution I don't want . I want the exact correct `id` which is in front of the current `max(check_in)`.

This is some sample data

```
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| id | org_entry_id | check_in            | check_out           | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at |
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
|  1 |            3 | 2018-04-03 01:48:07 | NULL                | 2018-04-03 13:53:29 | 2018-04-03 13:53:29 | NULL       |
|  2 |            3 | 2018-04-04 01:48:07 | 2018-04-04 01:48:07 | 2018-04-03 14:00:00 | 2018-04-03 15:23:52 | NULL       |
|  3 |            3 | 2018-04-04 01:48:07 | 2018-04-04 01:48:07 | 2018-04-03 14:00:30 | 2018-04-03 15:23:52 | NULL       |
|  4 |            3 | 2018-04-04 03:25:07 | NULL                | 2018-04-03 15:25:43 | 2018-04-03 15:25:43 | NULL       |
|  5 |            3 | 2018-04-05 01:25:07 | 2018-04-05 03:48:07 | 2018-04-03 15:26:01 | 2018-04-03 16:06:15 | NULL       |
|  6 |            3 | 2018-04-05 01:25:07 | NULL                | 2018-04-03 16:06:53 | 2018-04-03 16:06:53 | NULL       |
|  7 |            3 | 2018-04-05 03:25:07 | NULL                | 2018-04-03 16:07:22 | 2018-04-03 16:07:22 | NULL       |
+----+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Now the situation is I want `max(check_in)` and `id` for `org_entry_id` 3
that is `7` ,`2018-04-05 03:25:07` from the table.

Can there be any more possible solution for this .

Comment: please provide some sample data for the table

Comment: wait editing the question

Comment: I have edited the question please have a look

Comment: This is a VERY common question. :) Here's one top answwer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Comment: @Aaryan I have edited the question please have a look

Comment: @Vilx- I think in that group by is done by primary key but here I am doing group by non primary key

Comment: @Vikas - It doesn't matter. The solution is the same.

Comment: what is your previous output and what is your expecting output

Comment: @Vilx- No I want only the max value for particular org_entry_id and if I do group by id it will me all the rows . I want only one row with max time and its id

Comment: @Vikas - If there are multiple rows with the max `check_in` value for the same `org_entry_id` value, then which row do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `check_in` values are unique within each `org_entry_id`, or you don't care that there might be multiple rows for each `org_entry_id`:

```
select
    b.*
from
    (select org_entry_id , max(check_in) check_in from time_sheets group by org_entry_id) a
    join time_sheets b on (a.org_entry_id=b.org_entry_id and a.check_in=b.check_in)
```

If `check_in` values are NOT unique within each `org_entry_id`, but you still want one row for each `org_entry_id`:

```
select
    d.*
from
    (select
        max(b.id) id
      from
        (select org_entry_id , max(check_in) check_in from time_sheets group by org_entry_id) a
        join time_sheets b on (a.org_entry_id=b.org_entry_id and a.check_in=b.check_in)
      group by 
        a.org_entry_id
    ) c
    join time_sheets d on c.id=d.id
```

If you're filtering by a specific `org_entry_id` while `check_in` do not have unique values, but you still want just one row in return:

```
select
    *
from
    time_sheets
where
    org_entry_id=123
order by
    check_in desc,
    id
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, check_in
from time_sheets a inner join
(select org_entry_id, max(check_in) check_in
from time_sheets group by org_entry_id) b
on a.check_in=b.check_in and a.org_entry_id=b.org_entry_id;
```

You are supposed to use an aggregate function on the all the attributes that are in the select clause but not in the group by clause.

Comment: The entry with the maximum `id` might not be the same as the entry with the maximum `check_id`.

Comment: @Vilx- thanks for the comment, I just updated my query.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select max(id),org_entry_id, max(check_in) from time_sheets group by org_entry_id;
```

Comment: The entry with the maximum `id` might not be the same as the entry with the maximum `check_id`.